# Word for "translating" English to English

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for "translating" a work from period Modern English into contemporary English?  For example, if Locke's philosophies were rewritten point by point in contemporary English, would you say they had been translated?  Rendered?  Adapted?  Something else?

Comment: It's "translation" all the same. The word 'translation' has a very broad sense, including, "2 The conversion of something from one form or medium into another." ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/translation

Comment: @Kris - I disagree. The example given by the ODO for the definition you have presented is *"the translation of research findings into clinical practice"*, which is hardly equivalent to what the questioner is asking about. None of the other ODO definitions support your interpretation either.

Comment: yeah that's wrong Kris.  if you render Pride and Prejudice in to up to date language, that's not a translation.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Dutch has "vertalen" and "hertalen". The former means translating, but the latter misses an English equivalent. The Dutch word is common enough that Google should be able to find its English translation; Wikipedia doesn't have a link from the Dutch entry to an English equivalent. (The root "taal" is just language, the "ver" prefix commonly indicates movement, i.e. from one language to another, and the "her" prefix indicates repetition).

Comment: Elly van Gelderen, *A History of the English Language: Revised edition,* Google Books: 
 http://books.google.co.in/books?id=68EjAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22translate+into+modern+english%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zQgTVKj1N4ayuASujYLICA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22translate%22&f=false Perhaps also, [skeptics.se]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would describe the process of transforming a text written in a source language (e.g. Old English) that is largely unintelligible to readers of the target language (in this example, modern English) as *translation*.

*Adaptation* could refer either to the transformation of the work from one medium or format into another (e.g. the transformation of a novel into a screenplay), or to the rewriting of a text for a different audience (e.g. the simplification of a story first written for adults in order to make it easier for children to read).

Turning an archaic or old-fashioned text that is still largely intelligible in its original form into contemporary language is *modernization* or *updating* -- though the term *revision* has also been applied to modernized versions of the Bible in particular.

In my opinion, *modernization* would be the most appropriate term to describe the updating of the English of a text written by John Locke into modern English.

To *render* Text A into Text B is a general term that could be applied to any of these transformations (as too is the verb *transform*, of course).

Answer (score 0):

What a fantastic question!  I've always wondered this.

> if Locke's philosophies were rewritten point by point in contemporary
>   English...

.. what marketing term would be used on the cover?

So, James Frey is going to { whatever term } Locke's philosophies in to modern English.  What would it say on the cover?

I think **rendered** or **re-written** would be best.

I feel **adapted** is not really right because it has a specific clear and common use, in the field and the entertainment field generally, which is different. I fear **modernization** or **updating** could be interpreted as merely "fixing the spelling" ... making fairly small changes.

You're talking about a literary "cover-version", or perhaps "remix", or somewhere between the two.

Re Shakespeare, I've wondered if someone has done this?  And just what word would be best there. (As you go back further in time, plain "translation" is more fitting.)

Note that "in" could be useful in certain descriptions: For example, an excellent **title** for the book you describe could be:

> "John Locke in Modern English"

Note that a similar problem, to the problem you describe, comes in translating verse. So, the various translations of Homer etc are more often described as "versions of" or the like.  A further example is "translating" pop songs, a very arcane field. In that extreme case it's "nothing like" translating, the writer in question just has to write a totally new song, in English, that ideally has somewhat the same meanings, feelings. (You'd almost certainly just say "the XYZ version", it's not a translation.)

Answer (score 0):

The Bible has been translated into various languages. Bible Gateway considers the list as [versions](https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/)